# Insert a html code on clicking a link using jquery method insertBefore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a social website like facebook in php. I have a page for displaying the messages for the user with two links,that is `reply` and `delete` at the right bottom corner for every messages in the inbox. My issue is that when i click the reply link another html block should come where user can send the responses back to the sender.I have written the code like this

```
<div class="msgutil">
   <a href="" id="reply" onclick="return post_reply()" >reply</a>//this method does'nt works

   <a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>">delete</a> //dont check this
</div><!--end msgutil-->
```

I have inserted the html document inside the post_reply() like this

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function post_reply()
 {
    $("<form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="#"> <textarea name="replyfield"    id="replyfield"></textarea> </form>").insertBefore("#reply");
return true;
 }
 </script>
```

I don't know why its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using double quotes in a string made with double quotes. This cannot be done, as you keep ending and starting the string again.

Either surround it with single quotes:

```
$('<form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="#"> <textarea name="replyfield" id="replyfield"></textarea></form>').insertBefore("#reply");
//^                                                                                                              ^
```

or escape the double quotes:

```
$("<form id=\"msgreply\" name=\"msgreply\" action=\"#\"> <textarea name=\"replyfield\" id=\"replyfield\"></textarea></form>").insertBefore("#reply");
//          ^         ^       ^         ^         ^  ^                  ^           ^     ^           ^
```

You can also use the following HTML:

```
<div class="msgutil">
   <a href="#" id="reply">reply</a>
   <a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>">delete</a>
</div><!--end msgutil-->
```

and the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reply").click(function(e) {
        $('<form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="#"> <textarea name="replyfield" id="replyfield"></textarea></form>').insertBefore("#reply");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

to get the same result.

[Here's a JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xp29/1/)

Comment: @AnazA What error do you get in your javascript console if any? I've updated my example with a jsfiddle.

Comment: When I inspectthe reply link,i see this error  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i am getting DOM exception also

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow a better approach using jQuery as this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="msgutil">
   <a href="" id="reply">reply</a>

   <a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>">delete</a>
</div><!--end msgutil-->​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#reply").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formHtml = '<form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="#"> <textarea name="replyfield"    id="replyfield"></textarea> </form>';
    $(this).before(formHtml);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/3pXcA/1/)**
​